# Rewrite htaccess rule : hide the main url and call it on another url

Tags: .htaccess

I want to rewrite the URL to achieve this.

http://example.com/testcompany/login

should call to

http://example.com/u/testcompany/login

I tried like as below

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_=-]+)/login/{0,1}$      /u/$1/login
```

but it's not working.

Please let me how I can achieve this.

Comment: what is your original url ex. testcompany/login.php

Comment: no i am using cms where url is clean url not php file extension

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this, you can use it for any string in your given format we are rewriting to your working url.

try this in root.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)$ u/$1/$2 [NC,L]
```